# prove $\sum \limits_{cyc} \frac{x}{x+\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}}\leq 1$

Tags: inequality

> If $x$,$y$,$z$ are positive real numbers,Prove:$$\sum \limits_{cyc} \frac{x}{x+\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}}\leq 1$$ 
>   Using this two inequality:
>
> $\sum ^n_{i=1} \sqrt{a_ib_i}\leq\sqrt {ab} $ (we call it $A$ inequality)
>
> $\frac {ab}{a+b} \geq \sum ^n_{i=1} \frac{a_ib_i}{a_i+b_i}$ (we call it $B$ inequality)
>
> which $a_i$ and $b_i$ are positive and and $b= \sum ^n_{i=1} b_i$,$a= \sum ^n_{i=1} a_i$.
>
> Additional info: The question emphasizes in using inequalities $A$ and $B$.Beside them we can use AM-GM and Cauchy inequalities only.We are not allowed to use induction.And if you like,here you can see [Prove of inequality B](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881623/prove-frac-abab-geq-sum-n-i-1-fraca-ib-ia-ib-i).

*Things I have tried so far:*

Using inequality $A$ i can re write question inequality as$$\sum \limits_{cyc} \frac{x}{2x+\sqrt{xy}}\leq 1$$

And I can't go further.I can't observer something that could lead me to using inequality $B$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the fact 
$\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}\ge \sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{xz}$. Which is obvious after squaring and cancelling terms.
Now our inequality becomes :
$$\sum \limits_{cyc} \frac{x}{x+\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}}\le \sum \limits_{cyc} \frac{x}{x+\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{xz}}=\sum \limits_{cyc} \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}}=1$$

Comment: thanks for hint,i'm trying figuring out the part you write $\sum \frac{x}{x+\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{xz}}=1$.can you give me a hint on how you concluded that?

Comment: That was not a hint actually, its the full solution lol. Anyhoo I am editing it so you get a clearer idea.

Comment: How i missed a simple factoring like that.thanks.

Comment: So only inequality A is needed.

Comment: funny thing is Mathematica has [serious problem with it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2F%28x%2B%E2%88%9A%28xy%29%2B%E2%88%9A%28xz%29%29%29%2B%28y%2F%28y%2B%E2%88%9A%28yz%29%2B%E2%88%9A%28yx%29%29%29%2B%28z%2F%28z%2B%E2%88%9A%28zx%29%2B%E2%88%9A%28zy%29%29%29)

Answer (score 2):

By your work and by C-S we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{x+\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{2x+\sqrt{yz}}=\frac{3}{2}-\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{2x+\sqrt{yz}}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{yz}}{2x+\sqrt{yz}}=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{yz}{2x\sqrt{yz}+yz}\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{yz}\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2x\sqrt{yz}+yz)}=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

By AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{x}{x+\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}}=\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{x\left(\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}-x\right)}{xy+xz+yz}\leq\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{x\left(\frac{1}{2}(x+y+x+z)-x\right)}{xy+xz+yz}=1.$$